# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object On Orientation Change

Tags: android, cursor, android-lifecycle

I am using 1 Activity that inflates 2 fragments (2 panes) in case of sw600-land and 1 fragment case of sw600

both of the fragments implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

---

I'm initializing loader by (in `onStart`)

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(pm2_MAIN_LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

then I closed the cursor in `onLoadFinished`(at the last line of it) giving me the error so I have tried to close it somewhere else as the answers that I found on StackOverflow as `onDestroy` giving the same error

so when I can close the cursor?

Comment: If you're using a `CursorLoader`, you should not close the `Cursor` yourself. The `CursorLoader` will handle it.

Comment: thank you so much, maybe that was outdated in Google's intermediate course, also you can put that as an answer to get accepted and vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `CursorLoader` with the `Loader` framework, you should not `close()` the `Cursor` yourself. The `CursorLoader` will handle it.

Though the docs for `CursorLoader` don't specifically mention this, the general docs for [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) note it under [Using the LoaderManager Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#callback), in the **onLoadFinished** section.

> The loader will release the data once it knows the application is no longer using it. For example, if the data is a cursor from a [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), you should not call [`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close()) on it yourself. If the cursor is being placed in a [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), you should use the [`swapCursor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)) method so that the old [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) is not closed.